# How can I create/draw/render grid(plane) using directX?

Tags: grid, directx, directx-9, plane

I want to draw plane that picture.[image]

now I try vertex buffer and DrawPrimitive is D3DPT_LINESTRIP. but not effect I want.

so any way more than effective that???

please give me some advice. thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "not effect I want"? What did you actually get?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an option, is not the optimal but would achive that grid

```
void DrawGrid (float32 Size, CColor Color, int32 GridX, int32 GridZ)
{
  // Check if the size of the grid is null
        if( Size <= 0 )
                return;

  // Calculate the data
  DWORD grid_color_aux = Color.GetUint32Argb();
  float32 GridXStep = Size / GridX;
  float32 GridZStep = Size / GridZ;
  float32 halfSize = Size * 0.5f;

  // Set the attributes to the paint device
  m_pD3DDevice->SetTexture(0,NULL);
  m_pD3DDevice->SetFVF(CUSTOMVERTEX::getFlags());

  // Draw the lines of the X axis
  for( float32 i = -halfSize; i <= halfSize ; i+= GridXStep )
  {
    CUSTOMVERTEX v[] =
      { {i, 0.0f, -halfSize, grid_color_aux}, {i, 0.0f, halfSize, grid_color_aux} };

    m_pD3DDevice->DrawPrimitiveUP( D3DPT_LINELIST,1, v,sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
  }

  // Draw the lines of the Z axis
  for( float32 i = -halfSize; i <= halfSize ; i+= GridZStep )
  {
    CUSTOMVERTEX v[] =
    { {-halfSize, 0.0f, i, grid_color_aux}, {halfSize, 0.0f, i, grid_color_aux} };

    m_pD3DDevice->DrawPrimitiveUP( D3DPT_LINELIST,1, v,sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
  }
}
```

The CUSTOMVERTEX struct:

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
        float32 x, y, z;
        DWORD color;
        static unsigned int getFlags()
        {
                return D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX;
        }
};
```

Note: Is only a grid with lines, so you need to draw a solid plane, in order to get a look like result as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DrawPrimitive` with `D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP` for a plane. Then draw the indexed lines after with `D3DPT_LINELIST` with a **depth bias**. This way, even if they lie on the plane, you won't get any z-fighting.

Answer (score 0):

I will introduce you a book `Introduction to 3D programming with DirectX`,it has a great
detail on how to do this in Chapter 8,Section 4.